# Cannot save settings value

Tags: plugin-development, options

A plugin with its own settings page and a single text field is rendered. When a value is entered for the field and the form is submitted, `Settings saved.` is rendered. Yet a query of the database `wp_options` table shows that no value was stored for the setting; the option name `rma_base_url` exists in the table

Code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remote_member_auth_menu');

function remote_member_auth_menu() {
    add_options_page('Remote Member Auth Options', 'Remote Member Auth', 'manage_options', 'rma', 'remote_member_auth_options');
}

function remote_member_auth_options() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        wp_die(__('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.'));
    }
    echo '<div class="wrap">' .
        '<h3>Remote Member Authnetication Settings</h3>' .
        '<form method="post" action="options.php">';
    settings_fields('rma_options');
    do_settings_sections('rma');
    submit_button('Set base url');
    echo '</form>' .
        '</div>';
}

function register_rma_settings() {
    register_setting('rma_options', 'rma_base_url');
    add_settings_section('rma_main', '', 'rma_main_settings_fn', 'rma');
    add_settings_field('rma_base_url', 'Base URL', 'rma_base_url_string', 'rma', 'rma_main');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'register_rma_settings');

function rma_base_url_string() {
    $option = get_option('rma_base_url');
    echo "<input id='rma_base_url' name='rma_options[rma_base_url]' size='40' type='text' value='{$option}' />";
}

function rma_main_settings_fn() {
    echo '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the name attribute of the field from `name='rma_options[rma_base_url]'` to `name='rma_base_url'`